# Websocket using Glassfish + Nginx + Javascript

Tags: java, nginx, websocket, glassfish, jelastic

I'm trying to make a chat app using Websockets in JavaEE using Glassfish server and Javascript AngularJS for client side. I am using Nginx to proxy the connections.

Nginx config:

```
location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://10.10.127.78:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

In Glassfish admin page, I enabled the web socket mode and I ensured that the port is set to 8080.

The server side path is set to : `@ServerEndpoint(value = "/ws/chat/{room}")`.

OK, now the issue is that, I tried to connect to many addresses and each one gives some problems:

1. Tried to connect as localhost: `var serviceLocation = 'ws://localhost:8080/ws/chat/all/';` here the connection results in a `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/ws/chat/all/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
2. Tried to connect to server ip: `var serviceLocation = 'ws://10.10.127.78:8080/ws/chat/';` it results in connection timeout `WebSocket connection to 'ws://10.10.127.78:8080/ws/chat/all/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`
3. Tried to connect to the domain: var serviceLocation = 'ws://test.domain.com:8080/ws/chat/'; it results in a 404 `WebSocket connection to 'ws://test.domain.com:8080/ws/chat/all/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`

Can't get this to work. What can I try next ? Or what am I doing wrong ? If you need more info, leave a comment. Thank you, and hope someone can help.

I'm hosting all of this environments on Jelastic.

**UPDATE: Javascript code**

```
var wsocket;
var serviceLocation = 'ws://localhost:8080/ws/chat/';
//var serviceLocation = 'ws://10.10.127.78:8080/ws/chat/';
var nickName = $rootScope.loggedUser.user.firstName + " " + 
        $rootScope.loggedUser.user.lastName;
var room = 'all';
var $chatWindow = $('#response');


function onMessageReceived(evt) {
    var msg = JSON.parse(evt.data);
    var $appendedLine = $('<tr class="hidden-xs"><td>'+msg.received+' | '+msg.sender+'</td><td>'+msg.message+'</td></tr>\n\
                        <tr class="visible-xs"><td>'+msg.sender+': '+msg.message+'</td></tr>');
    $chatWindow.append($appendedLine);
}

function sendMessage() {
    var msg = '{"message":"' + $scope.message + '", "sender":"'
                    + nickName + '", "received":""}';
    wsocket.send(msg);
    $scope.message = "";
}

function connectToChatserver() {
    console.log(serviceLocation + room);
    wsocket = new WebSocket(serviceLocation + room);
    console.log("> ok");
    wsocket.onmessage = onMessageReceived;
    console.log("> connected to Web Socket server");
}


$scope.submitMessage = function() {
    sendMessage();
};


connectToChatserver();
```

**UPDATE: local test**

I tried to mirror the server to the local machine and test it locally without Nginx and it worked. Did I miss anything on Nginx, and it might be the cause of the issue ? Verified the proxy pass ip and port and they check out.

Comment: It looks to me like the first one is the correct one. Based on the other errors (timeout and a 404, which is HTTP not found) it looks like the resource isn't even found. A connection ***refused*** though, looks like the resource was found, but there was some misconfiguration which caused the server to reject the connection. Have you tried using something like JS runtime inspector in Chrome to add break points and debug your Javascript?

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for the tip, but it came up empty. I updated the post with the full Javascript code, maybe you can spot something I didn't.

Comment: In order to run WebSockets correctly it is necessary to add Public IP to the instance, I think this is should help to you. Also, have you contacted with your hosting provider support?

Comment: Yes i'm connecting with the Public IP, and yes i contacted the hosting provider support and we debugged the issue for several hours. We believe that it is from the Glassfish version or some issue from the jars of websockets that interfere with the Jelastic speficiations on the specific version of Glassfish. We are still trying to figure things out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out what was wrong and I want to share. The problem was the deployment to a glassfish 3.1.4 server with jdk 7 from a build made on a glassfish 4.1 with jdk 8 server. Ofc the issue occurred because of the jdk version, but because of the server version difference, the server didn't throw any version exception issues so I didn't see where the problem was coming from (forgot I was building from a jdk 8 server).